# Signing Edge WebExtension and UWP app in Visual Studio

Tags: uwp, microsoft-edge, code-signing, appx

I am developing a WebExtension for Edge. I implemented the example from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service and it is working. Creating and signing a standalone WebExtension worked and the resulting `.appx` installs the extension without problems. But now I need an AppServiceProvider for enabling native messaging. I want to build an `.appx` file that installs both the extension and the AppServiceProvider.

I added an own Chrome WebExtenion into a folder `Extension` under the AppServiceProvider project and adjusted it, so that a communication should work according to the documentation. I tried to install the WebExtension in Edge and the AppServiceProvider by double-clicking the resulting `AppServiceProvider_1.0.0.0_x86_Debug.appx`, which includes both. But I get an error message that I either must install a new certificate for this app packet or need a new app packet with trusted certificates. I created a self-signed certificate for testing purposes by following the instructions from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/appxpkg/how-to-create-a-package-signing-certificate and added it to TrustedPeople certificate storage. For a standalone WebExtension this worked, but how does the signing process work in Visual Studio?

Where have my `.pfx` file to be included in Visual Studio?

Are there other things that I have to consider?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By double-clicking `Package.appxmanifest` in the AppServiceProvider project, a menu with serveral categories opens. In the `Packaging` category click the `Choose Certificate...` button next to the publisher field and choose the .pfx file.

The appx package, created via `Create App Packages` wizard, will be signed with the private key configured before.

> The app manifest publisher name must exactly match the subject name of
>   the signing.

The appx can be installed via double-click and is working. But the WebExtension will not be installed in Edge.

References:

[Package a UWP app with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps)

[Sign an app package using SignTool](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/uwp/packaging/sign-app-package-using-signtool#common-errors-and-troubleshooting)

Answer (score 0):

**How to sign an assembly in Visual Studio**

You sign an application or component by using the Signing tab of the project properties window (right-click the project node in Solution Explorer and select Properties, or type project properties in the Quick Launch window, or press Alt+Enter inside Solution Explorer). Select the Signing tab, then select the Sign the assembly check box.

Specify a key file. If you choose to create a new key file, new key files are always created in the .pfx format. You need a name and password for the new file.

> Warning
>
> You should always protect your key file with a password to prevent
>   someone else from using it. You can also secure your keys by using
>   providers or certificate stores.

You can also point to a key you have already created. For more information about creating keys, see Create a public-private key pair.

If you only have access to a public key, you can use delay-signing to defer assigning the key. You enable delay signing by selecting the Delay sign only check box. A delay-signed project doesn't run, and you can't debug it. However, you can skip verification during development by using the Sn.exe strong name tool with the -Vr option.

Reference:

[How to sign an assembly in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-assembly-and-manifest-signing?view=vs-2017#how-to-sign-an-assembly-in-visual-studio)